# Can Hazelcast use Application server thread pool?

Tags: hazelcast

Hazel cast creates a number of threads. If my application is deployed in a j2ee environment, creating threads is discouraged. Is there a way to enable hazelcast to use application server managed threads?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that and there are no plans to make that happen.

Why do you think that app servers don't like you creating threads? I have done on quite a few and never had problems.